# php - How to insert a foreach loop inside a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json, mailchimp

How to insert a foreach loop inside a multidimensional array ?

I have a multidimensional array that I use to connect my website to Mailchimp. I have to check with a foreach loop the number of products that the user buys, and add these insiede a array call "lines".

This is at moment my json code, that after I will send to Mailchimp:

```
$json_data = '{
      "id": "2'. $order->id .'",
      "customer": {
        "id": "71",
        "email_address": "'.$order->email.'",
        "opt_in_status": true,
        "company": "'.$order->company_name.'",
        "first_name": "'.$order->pad_firstname.'",
        "last_name": "'.$order->pad_lastname.'",
        "orders_count": 1,
        "total_spent": 86
      },
      "checkout_url": "https://www.mywebsite.it/en/checkout/confirmation/",
      "currency_code": "EUR",
      "order_total": 86,
        "lines"[{
            '.$line_result.'
        }]
    }';
```

The **$line_result** is where I try to add the array of the products.
I know is wrong.

all the array inside the "lines" need be like this:

```
"lines":[
        {
            data product 1 ...
        },
        {
            data product 2 ...
        }
]
```

This is my foreach:

```
foreach ($order->pad_products as $product) {
        $line_result['line'] = array(
            "id" => "$order->id",
            "product_id" => "$product->pad_product_id",
            "product_title" => "$product->title",
            "product_variant_id" => "$product->id",
            "product_variant_title" => "$product->title",
            "quantity" => "$product->pad_quantity",
            "price" => "$product->prezzo",
        );
    };
```

what is the correct way to insert this data and create a multidimensional array like the one I need?
Thank you.

Comment: dont manually make the json instead use json_decode -> append the values -> json_encode..

Comment: thank you @LawrenceCherone. At moment in the output I see only array, do you mean json_decode the foreach before to add inside the array?

Comment: Yeah because your echoing an array into a string.. tbh $json_data should just be an array then you append the values and json_encode at the end

Comment: I advice you to consider your data model as an array instead the current json string. Bind data you need and then, encode global array in json to send it.

Comment: yes ok, but for keep the first data and not delete I don't have to use something like `array_push($results, $json_data)`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want say thank you to @adrianRosi for the help and the input he gives me.

In the end I find my solution, that it's `json_encode` the array before add into $data in json format.

in this way:

```
            $product_list = [];    

            foreach ($order->pad_products as $product) {
                $product_list[] = array(
                    "id" => "$id",
                    "..." => "...",
                );
            };

            $data_products['lines'] = $product_list;
            $json_products = json_encode($data_products);
            $json_products_edit = substr($json_products, 1, -1); // to delete the {}

            $prezzo_totale = $order->pad_price_total;

            $json_data = '{
                ...
                ...
                '.$json_products_edit.'
            }';
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to store all $line_result in global variable, and then, bind it to your json model :

```
$results = [];

foreach ($order->pad_products as $product) {
    $results[] = array(
        "id" => $order->id,
        "product_id" => $product->pad_product_id,
        "product_title" => $product->title,
        "product_variant_id" => $product->id,
        "product_variant_title" => $product->title,
        "quantity" => $product->pad_quantity,
        "price" => $product->prezzo,
    );
};

$data = json_decode($json_data, true);
$data['lines'] = $results;
$json = json_encode($data);
```

EDIT : Script array to json

```
$lines = [];

foreach ($order->pad_products as $product) {
    $lines[] = array(
        "id" => $order->id,
        "product_id" => $product->pad_product_id,
        "product_title" => $product->title,
        "product_variant_id" => $product->id,
        "product_variant_title" => $product->title,
        "quantity" => $product->pad_quantity,
        "price" => $product->prezzo,
    );
}

$data = [
    'id' => '2'.$order->id,
    'customer' => [
        'id' => '71',
        'email_address' => $order->email,
        'opt_in_status' => true,
        'company' => $order->company_name,
        'first_name' => $order->pad_firstname,
        'last_name' => $order->pad_lastname,
        'orders_count' => 1,
        'total_spent' => 86
    ],
    'checkout_url' => 'https://www.mywebsite.it/en/checkout/confirmation',
    'currency_code' => 'EUR',
    'order_total' => 86,
    'lines' => $lines
];

$jsonData = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Great! `$data['lines'] = $results;` this is the solution I did not know. But, now it correctly prints the array, but it deletes everything that was first inside `$json_data`

Comment: Do you call `$data = json_decode($json_data, true);` after making $json_data  ?

Comment: yes @splash58, I add exactly the same code. Now I try to add `$data['lines'] = $results; $json = json_encode($data);` inside the `$json_data` array and look works. But the `lines` appears inside a square brackets and this breaks my sending.

Comment: yes, the only problem that remains is that inside the array it is now missing the whole piece before the foreach. The foreach should integrate with the existing array

Comment: @adrienRosi I get the problem. the `json_decode` give me `null`

Comment: @AdrienRosi the output give me error because look like this: `\n\t\t\t\t\"id\": \"214945\"...`
I have find a solution thank to your tips but using the json format

  `$data['lines'] = $results;
  $json = json_encode($data); // code in JSON
  $json_edit = substr($json, 1, -1);` //this I need for the Mailchimp API

and just add the `$json_edit`  inside the JSON array.